# Separating a column results in two new, empty columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of names, of the format "FIRST.LAST", that I'm trying to separate into two new columns.

```
my_df <- my_df %>% separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = '.')
```

The two new columns are created, but they're blank. Suggestions as to why that might be?

Answer (score 2):

We can escape the `.` as `.` is a metacharacter which implies any character instead of the literal dot and as the `sep` argument takes regex, it could get mistaken that it is any character.  According to `?separate`

> sep - If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The
>   default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of
>   non-alphanumeric values.

So, we can either escape with `\\`

```
my_df %>% 
   separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = '\\.')
```

Or place it inside square brackets to evaluate as the literal dot

```
my_df %>% 
   separate(name, c("first_name", "last_name"), sep = '[.]')
```

#### data

```
my_df <- data.frame(name = c('abcd.defg', 'acdf.dagd'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```